# Select parcels from SDE layer using table list and exporting to shapefiles

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, modelbuilder

Using a table of county fips codes and state name, I need to select from a large parcel layer stored in SDE and export to individual shapefiles based on the fips code and state name from the table.  Can this be done with a Python script or ModelBuilder?

Comment: Certainly!  What do you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. I'd suggest skipping ModelBuilder and go for an ArcPy based solution.

You would need to iterate through the table with county codes and states and for each code/state (depending on your business logic) select and export shapefiles. Take a look at [search cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000011000000). [Select Layer By Attribute](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000071000000) or [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Make_Feature_Layer/00170000006p000000/) will help you when setting the SQL expression. Exporting a shapefile is easiest with [Copy Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Copy_Features/001700000035000000/).

Comment: I'm not a Python script writer so a few lines of code would help. Here's what I have so far:import arcpy
... fc = r"Database Connections\LAND_P.sde\PARCELS.PARCELS"
... shortName = "parcel_stmn"
... fipsField = "FIPS"
... outputFolder = r"S:\General-Offices-GO-Trans\SLR-Mapping\GIS_Analysis\GIS_Data\Minnesota_County_Parcels\from_landp"

Comment: @JimFritz, this should go into the question body. If you not comfortable with Python, consider using ModelBuilder then. Drag,drop,connect.